# How to sniff domain name from dns traffic using scapy?

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I have achieved sniffing IP packets. I use the following code.

```
def print_summary(pkt):
    print("SRC:", pkt[scapy.IP].src, "\t\tDEST:", pkt[scapy.IP].dst)

scapy.sniff( iface=interface, filter="ip", prn=print_summary)
```

If I try to ping a domain name say 'youtube.com' or open it using a web browser, how can I show the domain name using the above `print_summary` function. I have tried searching for what filters to use for dns but found nothing.

Comment: DNS uses port 53 on UDP or TCP. However names can be compressed so you can't just look at a packet to match specific name. Scapy has a decoder and documentation on this: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.dns.html   Also do note that more and more web browsers are using DNS over HTTPS, in which case you won't be able to see anything in the DNS data. But as it stands your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I get it now. What I did was to remove the filter argument altogether from the `sniff()` method.

```
scapy.sniff( iface=interface, prn=print_summary)
```

Then in the `print_summary()` function, I filtered according to the layer each packet had (IP or DNS).

```
def print_summary(pkt):
  if scapy.IP in pkt:
    print("SRC:", pkt[scapy.IP].src, "\t\tDEST:", pkt[scapy.IP].dst)
  
  if scapy.DNS in pkt:
    print("Domain:", pkt.[scapy.DNS].qd.qname.decode("utf-8"))
```

`decode("utf-8")` because the qname is a utf encoded byte string.